# Given $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = r$, show $\lim\limits_k\int_{[0,a]}f(kx) = ar$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Show $\lim\limits_k\int_{[0,a]}f(kx) = ar$ where $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, bounded, Lebesgue measurable, and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) = r$.

$$
\int_{[0,a]}f(kx) = \int \chi_{[0,a]}(x)f(kx) = \int \chi_{[0,ka]}(kx)f(kx) = \frac{1}{k}\int\chi_{[0,ka]}(x)f(x) \\
= a\frac{1}{ak}\int\chi_{[0,ka]}(x)f(x)
$$

I'm stuck at showing 
$$
\frac{1}{ak}\int\chi_{[0,ka]}(x)f(x) \to r.
$$

Comment: Have you tried change of variables already? What have you tried?

Comment: @William Yes, I'll show it in a moment.

Comment: Use the fact that since $f(x)\rightarrow r$, you can find an $N>0$ such that $|f(x)-r|<\epsilon$ for all $x\geq N$. Since $N$ is fixed, you can take the limit, and then let $\epsilon$ go to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $f_k(x)=f(kx)$ then we have $$\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=r\;\text{ a.e.}$$
so by the dominated convergence theorem we have

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^a f_k(x)dx=\int_0^a rdx=ra$$

Comment: By what integrable function are $\chi_{[0,a]}f_k$ dominated?

Comment: The function $f$ is bounded by say $M$ and the constant function equal to $M$ is integrable over $[0,a]$.